# Why do some kanji have the  radical on top when apparently they shouldn't?

Tags: words, radicals

I have been studying vocabulary from tea descriptions and I found two kanji that have the radical  「ひとやね」on top but they can't be found in any dictionary, there are kanji without the radical that I mentioned before that do exist.

Those words are names of brands so I think it could be added to improve the visual design but I certainly don't know.

One kanji is 嘉「か」from the tea brand Yamamotoyama (山本山)

Tho other one is the kanji 東「ひがし」which is followed by the brand name 放香堂 which is read as Hokodo (only the three last kanji).

These two kanji have the  on top and no dictionary has any information about it.
Does anyone know what is it about?

Reference images below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems [山本山](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/山本山) and [放香堂](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/放香堂) were founded by 山本**嘉**兵衛 and **東**源兵衛, respectively.

Comment: So, after all, it's all about commercial names; thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a reference for what these are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_rebus_monogram). In the logo for Yamamotoyama, the -like shape visually signifies 山, and is not a kanji part.

They should be thought of as logos and are not always readable directly, although they may suggest part of the name of the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks for the information, now everything makes sense !